# Cant' get MongoDB PHP Extension to work

Tags: macos, mongodb

I've been following this tutorial to try to install the PHP MongoDB extension but unfortunately haven't been able to get it working.

http://www.marcwitteveen.com/tech/mac/installing-mongodb-on-a-mac-so-you-can-access-it-with-php/

I can access the collections in the terminal, the database is properly installed but I didn't manage to get the extension working.

I have the following problem:

```
Sinan-MBP:mongo-php-driver-master Sinan$ cd
Sinan-MBP:~ Sinan$ sudo pecl install mongo
pecl/mongo is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.4.1
install failed
```

I've been trying several times so that's probably why I get this message. However, even after adding "extension=mongo.so" to the php.ini, I can't use MongoDB in my PHP code.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Whats the output of php -i | grep mongo

Comment: Nothing, there is no output actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it was not working but I found a workaround late last night.

I uninstalled the php extension and then installed it again and made sure the extension was loaded in the php.ini

```
sudo pecl uninstall mongo
sudo pecl install mongo
```

Answer (score 2):

This is likely a case of modifying the wrong `php.ini` for the environment, or PHP not being able to find the `mongo.so` in its directory. If you have separate `php.ini` files for CLI and web environments, PECL might have installed the compiled extension to a different directory.

If you run through the [installation docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php), there are instructions for grepping `extension_dir` from `php -i` and ensuring that `mongo.so` is present in that directory. If your web environment has a separate `php.ini` file, then grepping output from `php -i` likely won't help. You may need to view `phpinfo();` output through your web server and check for the extension directory there.

One additional test that PECL installation succeeded would be attempting to view reflection information for one of the driver classes from the CLI environment. You can do so with `php --rc MongoClient`, which should print info on the methods of the MongoClient class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't think I was modifying the wrong php.ini though, that was probably a problem related to the installation of the extension